# Dynamically change currency format per range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Does anyone know how to change in Google sheet the currency in specific range using Apps Script?

I have a script:

```
const SHEET_NAME = 'Sheet1';
const CUR_CELL = 'A3';
const FORMAT_COLUMN = 'B';
const CURS = {
  dollar: '$',
  euro: '€',
};

function onEdit(e) {
  let sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() !== SHEET_NAME
    || e.range.getA1Notation() !== CUR_CELL.toUpperCase()) return;
  let len = sheet.getLastRow() - 1;
  sheet.getRange(2, FORMAT_COLUMN.toUpperCase().charCodeAt() - 64, len)
    .setNumberFormats(new Array(len).fill().map(_ =>        [`${CURS[e.value.toLowerCase()]}#,###.00`]));
}
```

This script change the currency for a whole column.
But for me, not every numbers in a column have to change to a currency. Also I want to change multiple columns so I only want to change a range.

I made an example to explain (see screenshot).

Example screenshot

[image: 1]

The value in A3 (dropdown list) should decide what the currency is in B3:B5 and C6:C8.
(B7 and C5 should stay numbers).

Can somebody help me with change the script?
I already tried a lot but I can't find it working.

Thank you!

Kim

Comment: About `The value in A3 (dropdown list) should decide what the currency is in B3:B5 and C6:C8. (B7 and C5 should stay numbers).`, how can we confirm `B3:B5` and `C6:C8` from your situation? For example, your expected ranges are always fixed as `B3:B5` and `C6:C8`? And, can I ask you about the detail of `but I can't find it working`?

Comment: Yes, I have multiple ranges but they are always fixed. 

I already tried some things on my own to change the script but I'm not a professional so it is hard to find the solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Sheet.getRangeList().setNumberFormat()`, like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const settings = {
    rangesA1: ['B3:B5', 'C6:C8',],
    dollar: '$',
    euro: '€',
  };
  let sheet;
  if (!e || !e.value) {
    return;
  }
  const currency = settings[e.value.toLowerCase()];
  if (!currency
    || e.range.getA1Notation() !== 'A3'
    || (sheet = e.range.getSheet()).getName() !== 'Sheet1') {
    return;
  }
  const format = `${currency}#,###.00`;
  sheet.getRangeList(settings.rangesA1).setNumberFormat(format);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 

When I want to save this script I get:
'Syntax error: Unexpected token '{' line: 14 file: Code.gs

Comment: It still stays the same. Is there something else I could try?

Comment: In the code I gave you, line 14 is ``const format = `${currency}#,###.00`;`` which uses a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Make sure you are using backticks ` instead of single quotes '. Consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet where the issue can be reproduced. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Comment: It is working with the backticks, thank you! To test this I was always working with 1 sheets but in real I'm working with multiple sheets. So the value in A3 on Sheet1 decides what the currency should be for all the sheets. But for example on Sheet2 the range is B3:B5 and C6:C8 and on Sheet3 the range is D1:D5 and E6:E8. How do I place this in the script?

Comment: That is a different question that will require a different solution. Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Post a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).